# Drop down value replicates in nog options Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I have a dynamically generated html table that adds rows based on the record that is displayed.  I'm adding a column that will contain a dropdown.  I used ng-options for it, however every time I change one record, the rest are also updated. Tried changing it to ng-repeat and get the same result.  See code below:

```
        <td>    

       <select class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedRC" ng-    options="r.ccd as (r.OName + ' -- '+ r.RCName)  for r in $ctrl.RC track by r.ccd"> </select>
<!--if I have 5 records, all dropdowns in the table change -->
    </td>
```

Using ng-repeat:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedRC" <option value="" ng-selected="true">--Select one--</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="r in $ctrl.RC"
                        value="{{r.OName}}"
                        ng-selected="{{r.OName === selectedRC}}">{{r.RCName}}
                        </option>

                        </select>
```

I know that these two are currently displaying two different things (one a concatenated set of values, the other juts one).  But my main interest is to figure out how to have each `<td>` have its own dropdown without affecting the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because you use the same ng-model for all rows.

You need to define a different one for each row.

You do this:

`ng-model="$ctrl.selectedRC"`

but you need something like this:

`ng-model="$ctrl.selectedRC[$index]"`

where $index is your reference to the row.

Comment: See for example this jsbin i've created: http://jsbin.com/pasixujica/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you!  However now I'm unable to display my selection since it disappears :(

Comment: <select class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedRC[$index]" <option value="" ng-selected="true">--Select one--</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="r in $ctrl.RC"
                        value="{{r.OName}}"
                        ng-selected="{{r.OName === selectedRC}}">{{r.RCName}}
                        </option>

Comment: As i told you $index is an example, i said "something like this", not "copy this". Have you see my jsbin example?

Comment: I did the same in the one where I used ng-options and it does the same :(

Comment: Oh I missed the link the example, let me see.  TY!